# Conflicto con css en la misma web

Tags: css

Tengo  un menú  que cargo en la pagina principal,

```
$menuPrincipal= /*Variable donde voy a guardar el menu*/
            "<nav class='menu-container'>".
                "<a href='#' class='menu-btn'><i class='fa fa-bars fa-lg'></i> <b>Menu</b></a>".
                "<div class='menu-slide'>".
                    "<ul class='menu-list'>";
                        if (isset($_SESSION['PlnDir']['apiKey'])){ 
                            $menuPrincipal.="<li class='menu-item'><a href=javascript:PlnDir(\"tareas.html\",\"PlnDir\",\"tarea\");> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> <b>Plan Director<b></a></li>".
                            "<li class='menu-item'><a href=javascript:PlnDir(\"pruebas.html\",\"PlnDir\",\"tarea\");> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> <b>Pruebas<b></a></li>";
                            $count=1;
                        }
                        if (isset($_SESSION['agr_app']['apiKey'])){ 
                            $menuPrincipal.="<li class='menu-item'><a  href=javascript:PlnDir(\"convenios.html\",\"agr_app\",\"convenios\");><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cloud'></span><b>  Familia La Caña</b></a></li>";
                             $count=$count+2;
                        }
    $menuPrincipal.= "</ul>".
                "</div>".
            "</nav>";
```

En un div de la pagina principal, cargo otra pagina con un css diferente, teninedo dos css, el de  la pagina principal y el de la pagina secundaria cargada dentro de la principal.
 El problema esta en que el css de la secundaria me afecta con el css del menu principal.

Me es muy trabajoso hacer una prueba en html ya que todo el codigo está en js y php. Lo que me gustaría saber es que se hace en un caso como este.

Este código afecta al menú y no quiero que suceda eso.
ul{
        text-align:center;
    }
    li{
        list-style-position: inside;
    }

Comment: Afecta al menú puesto que esas declaraciones de CSS afectan a **TODOS** los elementos `ul` y  `li` que encuentre

Comment: ¿Entonces qué quieres que haga el css?

Comment: ¿Y podrías mostrar el HTML tal cual se renderiza en el cliente? No tiene ningún sentido que lo pegues como código PHP que no podemos evaluar y que nos hace mucho más difícil interpretar qué termina siendo!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que sobrescribir los estilos para tu página principal, usa ids para diferenciar tus elementos `<ul>` y `<li>`

*Página principal*
`<ul id="menu-principal"> <!-- para tu página principal -->`

*Página secundaria*
`<ul id="menu-secundaria"> <!-- para tu página principal -->`

**CSS**

```
    #menu-principal{
       /* estilos página principal*/
    }
    #menu-principal li{
       /* estilos página principal*/
    }
    #menu-secundaria{
       /* estilos página secundaria*/
    }
    #menu-secundaria li{
       /* estilos página secundaria*/
    }
```